# Trial Division Prime Factorization using PHP

Tags: php, prime-factoring

I'm currently working on a function to get prime factors by trial division of a number (particularly a large number) and I am stumped by my results. Below is my PHP code. I was able to get the correct results with a javascript variant of this code but PHP does not give me the results.

```
function primeFactors($n) {
$primeNumbers = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 
53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 
131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 
211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281,
283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 
383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449,
457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 
563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619,
631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 
733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811,
821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 
919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997];
$factors = [];

for ($i = 0, $p=$primeNumbers[$i]; $i < count($primeNumbers) && $p*$p<=$n; 
$i++, $p=$primeNumbers[$i]) {
 while ($n % $p == 0) {
  $factors[] = $n;
  $n = $n /$p;
 }
}
if ($n>1)
{
 $factors[] = $n;
}
var_dump($factors);
return $factors;
}
```

Appreciate It.

Comment: So, the thing you're stumped by is that it didn't return any results? Please be more specific, e.g. it timed out, there's nothing in the array, it threw an error, etc. Also, if you could post your JS code and what number you're passing into `primeFactors`, that'd be helpful too.

Comment: i converted the function back to js and it still gives the same (wrong) result as it does in php. primeFactors(12) gives me 12,6,3 in JS and php (instead of 2,2,3)

Comment: so if your JS code is correct, something must have been lost in translation when you went to php, so again the original JS would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the wrong number into the factors array...

```
$factors[] = $n;
```

Is adding the original number in, think you meant to add the factor in

```
$factors[] = $p;
```

This is a good example (IMHO) of giving fields meaningful names as this would have been more obvious.